# Splitting to data packets for udp but data not send correctly

Tags: arrays, c, struct

Im trying to accomplish a udp socket data send and receive, where data will be send as small packets,
my function splits the data and send serially, then at receiver end, I combine them

my data input is like this

```
    typedef struct SenderData {
    unsigned short CommandCode;
    int DataSize;
    void *Data;
     } SenderData;
```

my function goes like this

```
    int send_packets(SenderData pkt_data,int pkt_size)
{
    int data_size=0;
    int no_cyc=0;
    int rem_data=0;
    int ndx=0;
    int forloop_size=0;
    int pending_size=0;
    // find the size of data
    data_size=pkt_data.DataSize;
    if(data_size>pkt_size)
    {
        // find no of cycle required to send data
        no_cyc=data_size/pkt_size;
        // find remaining data
        rem_data=data_size%pkt_size;
        void *complete_data = pkt_data.Data;
        void*data_out;
        for(ndx=0;ndx<no_cyc;ndx++)
        {
            // store pkt size to data out;
            memmove( data_out, (complete_data+(ndx*sizeof(int)*pkt_size)),pkt_size);
            if (sendto(sd, data_out, pkt_size, 0,(struct sockaddr*)&groupSock,sizeof(groupSock)) < 0)
            {
                perror("sending datagram message");
            }
        }
        forloop_size=no_cyc*pkt_size;
        // remaining data size is
        pending_size=forloop_size-rem_data;
        // send remaining data
        memmove( data_out,(complete_data+forloop_size), pending_size);
        if (sendto(sd, data_out, pending_size, 0,(struct sockaddr*)&groupSock,sizeof(groupSock)) < 0)
        {
            perror("sending datagram message");
        }

    }


    return 0;
}
```

data being send is

```
 int cont[202];
 SenderData data;


 data.DataSize=sizeof(cont);
 data.Data=&cont;
```

and my function call is like this

```
 send_packets(data,100);
```

im doing the reverse of this function at receipt end

but when i run the code, it seams my data transfer has some issue, when i print the count array at the receipt end, im getting long numbers instead of data

Comment: The order of arguments for the [`memmove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove) function isn't what you seem to expect.

Comment: i tried the other order too but same results

Comment: Do you know that UDP is by design an unreliable protocol? Read this description: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol If you need reliability, you'll either use TCP or implement yourself everything required to fix the possible errors (Packet lost, packet order not respected, duplicate packet and more) and you will probably reinvent TCP.